# Troubleshooting People-Picker errors in multi-domain environment

Tags: active-directory, people-picker

I'm looking for help with troubleshooting people-picker in multi-domain environment with one-way trusts.
 We already executed the

`stsadm –o setapppassword -password pickapassword`
and
 `stsadm -o setproperty -url http://server:port -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests`  commands.

Before these commands were executed people-picker could find users from the local sharepoint domain. After running the commands, people-picker shows "callback error" *immediately* upon launching search.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sofocle/archive/2011/05/17/sharepoint-2010-people-picker-issue-quot-there-was-an-error-in-the-callback-quot.aspx and http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/06027570-845e-482d-b55f-8b89a0461200/

Comment: I had this problem recently (SharePoint 2010) and the WSS_WPG group needs to have READ access to the registry key mentioned in the first blog in the comment above.

HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\14.0\Secure

Answer (score 1):

When you are configuring yoru people picker, you need to specify ALL forest/domains that you are utilizing.